# Google Colabs - Mobile - Blank code cells

Tags: google-colaboratory

If I visit a Google Colab on Google Chrome on Android or through Discord app browser, all my code cells will load blank. On top of that, the notebook saves right away yielding a blank notebook to history.

What is causing this? And how can I prevent it? If the browser is in Desktop mode this doesn't happen but isn't always set to on by default.

Comment: Same issue. when collabs is loaded on android mobile, some code cell are wiped

Answer (score 1):

The issue in on mobile version only.
If you pass on desktop version, no cells are wiped!
After you pass on desktop version,you can use version history to restore you lost code!

But where i can post this issue? Google must fix the mobile version!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's incredible that this issue hasn't been fixed, especially since it used to work IIRC a few years back.

Comment: Looks more like a comment rather than the answer.